# Forward argument list to a function

Tags: function, scala, arguments

I have a class implementing some functionality (providing a turtle graphics interface for L-systems, but that is not important here):

```
abstract class LSystem
{
  def BranchBegin()
  def BranchEnd()
  def Rotate(axis:Vector3f, angle:Float)
  def MoveForward(dist:Float)
  def DrawForward(size:Float, color:ColorRGBA)
  def DrawSphere(size:Float, color:ColorRGBA)
}
```

I have a a trait prodiving some helpers:

```
trait LSystemShortcuts {
  def < ()(implicit lsys:LSystem)= lsys.BranchBegin()
  def S(size:Float, color:ColorRGBA)(implicit lsys:LSystem)= lsys.DrawSphere(size,color)
  def > ()(implicit lsys:LSystem)= lsys.BranchEnd()
}
```

And finally there is an individual L-system, looking like this:

```
class RoundTree(implicit lsys:LSystem) extends LSystemShortcuts {
  // TODO: move to LSystemShortcuts 
  def F = lsys.DrawForward _
  def R = lsys.Rotate _
  def M = lsys.MoveForward _

  val degree = PI.toFloat/180
  val colorCrown = ColorRGBA.SRGB(0.1f,0.4f,0.05f, 1)
  val colorTrunk = ColorRGBA.SRGB(0.1f,0.1f,0.05f,1)

  def C(size:Float, iterations:Int) = {
    if (iterations>0) {

      F(size*0.5f,colorTrunk)

      <
      C(size*0.5f,iterations-1)
      >

      <
      R(Vector3f(0,0,1),+75*degree)
      C(size*0.3f,iterations-1)
      >

      // some more rendering code here

    }
    else
    {
      F(size,colorTrunk)
      M(size*0.6f)
      S(size*0.7f,colorCrown)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that currently shortcuts `F`, `R` and `M` are defined directly in the `RoundTree` class. I would like to move it to the `LSystemShortcuts` trait, but I would like to avoid having to repeat the argument lists (this is currently done by using partially applied function), like it was done for S shortcut. It would be easy to use `LSystemShortcuts` as a base class instead, but I do not like such design, trait seems more appropriate.

Is there some way to forward argument lists when defining functions? Something along lines of:

```
def R(_)(implicit lsys:LSystem) = lsys.Rotate _
```

Or perhaps some other design, having `LSystemShortcuts` as a member instead of a trait, which would allow me to achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can guess of a kind of a dirty workaround. You could alter the definition of your `trait` with a protected member.

```
trait A {
  protected var i: Int = 0  // has to be initialized, won't compile otherwise
  def print = println(i)
}
```

Afterwards you could use that member as follows:

```
class B extends A {
  i = 10
  print
}
```

A call of `new B()` will print `10` to the console.

I hope this answers your question as intended. Otherwise I will be glad to try and work out another solution.

Comment: I think this can be modified into something which works perfect: I can have (uninitialized, abstract) val lsys:LSystem in the trait. Then RoundTree implements this, and the trait can use it. Why Int has to be initialized? I though a trait can contain abstact values.

Comment: In your case it could be: in the trait A def i : Int and in the class B val i = 10.

Comment: I tried that, in the REPL and it told me, that I cannot write it that way, without initializing it first. But if it works for you, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible, since scala does not support [point-free style notation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) as Haskell does.

I'm afraid there's no way of passing the arguments other than explicitly.